# Wordpress PHP quiz - code to recall answer recalls all past submissions as well

Tags: php, wordpress

Sorry if the answer to this question is blindingly obvious, I’ve only just started learning Php so I’m not 100% sure on what I’m doing.

I’ve got a quiz that users fill out on wordpress using the plugin FSQM Pro and when they submit it they are redirected to a page that will display some text along with their answer to a question in the quiz. To recall the answer they submit, I have used this code:

```
<?php global $wpdb, $ipt_fsqm_info;
$form_id = 9;
$data_ids = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT id FROM {$ipt_fsqm_info['data_table']} WHERE form_id = %d", $form_id ) );
foreach ( $data_ids as $data_id ) {
$data = new IPT_FSQM_Form_Elements_Data( $data_id );
echo wpautop( $data->data->pinfo[13]['value'] );
}
?>
```

However when I execute it, it returns all the values that the user has ever entered for that question with the most recent value at the bottom.

How do I get it to output only the most recent value?

Comment: Please share the output of var_dump($data_ids) and var_dump($data) here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can modify your MySQL query, by using `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` clauses, like this:

`$data_ids = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT id FROM {$ipt_fsqm_info['data_table']} WHERE form_id = %d ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,1", $form_id ) );`

Comment: Is there a way to modify it to only return the results from the current user?

Comment: Yes, add first: `$user_ID = get_current_user_id();` and then 
in `WHERE` clause add `WHERE form_id = %d AND user = $user_ID`